# Xampp crash TCP table returns negative number

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tcp, xampp

I am working on an application that retrieves big datasets from an MySQL database. Retrieving all the data (+- 3000 records) works fine the first time. However when I then try to refresh my application (which just retrieves all the data again) Xampp crashes and gives me the following error:

```
[NetStatTable] Problem loading NetStat TCP table: Returned -1073741823
[EXCEPTION] System Error. Code: 6
[EXCEPTION] Acces violation at adress 005AA712 in module 'xampp-control.exe' Read of address 00000 {can't read the line ending as I can not scroll once it crashes}
```

I have tried giving Xampp more resources as I thought it was crashing because I was simply retrieving too much data. That however did not work. I don't think it could be the Java program itself. If it would've been bad queries it should've been the JDBC connector giving me an exception in the program.

Comment: How are you using Java on XAMPP?

Comment: I should've mentioned, the Java application is a separate program.

Comment: Having the same issue.  No problems until today, when restoring a backup of one table while running intense operations on another in Java.

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure out What is causing this error. I have been able to work around this by refactoring my queries though. @ndm13